# Finding subsequences $\mathbf{c}$ of $\mathbf{b}$ such that $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c} \equiv 0\bmod t$ for fixed sequences $\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

**The Problem**

> Let $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ and $b_1,\cdots,b_m$ be sequences of positive integers with $m>n$, and let $t$ be a positive integer coprime to all elements of $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$. What is a computationally efficient way to find all $n$-element subsequences $c_1,\cdots,c_n$ of $\{b_i\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ic_i \equiv 0\bmod t$ (or does no way exist)?

(Note: In the particular cases with which I am concerned, $m\approx 1.6\cdot n$ and $t \approx \frac{2^n}{n^2}.$)

**My Progress**

So far, I haven't really made much progress. The brute force method requires ${n\choose m}$ tests, which is horribly inefficient if $m$ and $n$ are at all large. Any recursive or backtracking-recursive implementation will still end up going through all ${n\choose m}$ cases at some point. Once one has chosen $c_1,\cdots,c_{n-1}$, one can calculate $c_n\bmod t$ by noting that

$$c_na_n \equiv -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c_i a_i\bmod t \implies c_n \equiv -a_n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c_i a_i\bmod t$$

and then check whether this is actually a valid value for $c_n$ (the lookup on $c_n$ can be done in $O(1)$ time if $n$ is a reasonable number and the value of $a_n^{-1}$ can probably be precomputed in a small amount of time), but this still only reduces the calculation to ${n-1 \choose m-1}$ cases, which is not much better, if it is even faster at all.

The only other idea I had was that we can first attempt to find a superset of solutions by completely neglecting the order and just looking at the set of products of elements of $\{a_i\}$ with those of $\{b_i\}$. From there we simply need to find all $n$-element subsets with sums $0\bmod t$ (and then weed out those with duplicated elements of $a_i$ or $b_i$, or those whose $b_i$ elements are in the wrong order; perhaps this could be done as part of the algorithm to help reduce extraneous calculations). Even though the brute-force method is significantly worse in this simplification, it *feels* like an easier problem to deal with and maybe one that has a nicer solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something in $O(m^2nt+kn)$, where $k$ denotes the number of valid subsequences that you seek.

There are two steps. First you figure out every possible partial sums you can obtain such that $c_i=b_j$, while remembering the previous element in the subsequence, then you backtrack which sums reach $0 \bmod t$.

---

For the first step, you build a data structure $S$ of size $n\times m\times t\times m$, such that $S(i,j,s,l)=1$ if there exists a subsequence $c_1,\ldots,c_i$ with :

- $c_{i-1}=b_l$
- $c_i=b_j$
- $\sum_{\lambda=1}^ia_\lambda c_\lambda \equiv s\bmod t$

Otherwise, $S(i,j,s,l)=0$.

If you know the proper values of $S$ for a given "slice" $i$, it's easy to deduce the values for the next "slice" $i+1$. For a non-zero
$S(i,j,s,.)$, assign $S(i+1,j',s',j) \gets 1$ for all $j+1\le j'\le m-n+i+1$, where
$s'\equiv s+a_{i+1}b_{j'}\bmod t$.

Obtaining the new "slice" takes $O(m^2t)$ time, repeated $n$ times for the whole structure.

---

Once you have $S$, inspect the last "slice" at $s=0$, you obtain tuples of values $j,l$ such that $S(n,j,0,l)=1$. This means that there is a subsequence $c$ with $c_n=b_j$, and $c_{n-1}=b_l$. To figure out the rest of the subsequence, inspect the previous "slice" $n-1$ at $s\equiv -a_nb_j \bmod t$ and $j'=l$. Or in other words, find the values $l'$ such that
$S(n-1,l,-a_nb_j,l')$ is equal to $1$.
Repeat until you reach the first "slice".

This step can be done in $O(kn)$ time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it's a good one when $t$ is rather small, but in the case I'm dealing with (as I forgot to mention), large $t$ (probably on the order of $2^n/n^2$). I don't see an easy way to simplify this algorithm so that it becomes efficient for large $t$, but I think it is quite a good one when $t$ is small!

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Indeed, for that kind of $t$ value this doesn't look very practical... If you can afford to compute the prime decomposition of $t=\prod_i t_i^{\alpha_i}$, and if the magnitude of each $t_i^{\alpha_i}$ isn't too large, you could try to apply this method on each $t_i^{\alpha_i}$ and apply the Chinese remainder theorem... If $t$ is itself a prime or some factor has a very large magnitude, I'm out of ideas.